# Click without id and name

Tags: javascript

How do I click this link that has no name and ID.

I tried that way but it did not work.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-success btn-lg get-link')[0].click()
```

```html
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/" class="btn btn-success btn-lg get-link">Get Link</a>
```

Needed without JavaScript, jQuery can not because the code is executed in C #.

Comment: Do you actually have to "click" the link, or does it suffice for you to just open the link in a new window/tab?

Comment: Why are you opposed to using javascript or jquery?

Comment: I don't see why that wouldn't work. Check to see if getElementsByClassName is returning what you expect.

Comment: Check the element in the browser's console in case the class name changes before your script runs

Comment: Do you have another element with the same class names? It might be possible that you are trying to click the wrong link/element

Comment: The most likely reason is that you run your JavaScript code before the DOM has loaded completely therefor the link does not exist yet.

Comment: Could you post the full code?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just giving it an ID?

Comment: With jQuery you can call .trigger('click'), maybe you can watch it's code.

Comment: Hello, use document.getElementByTagName("a")[0].

Comment: Or querySelector (but i haven't code with that statement).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way to open link for user.

```
function URL() {
location.href = 'http://your.url.here';
}
```